# Simple LESS mixin and variable causing compiling error

Tags: less

I'm trying to discover why this LESS file will not compile. I've created a basic mixin and variable being parsed into it, but for some reason it won't compile.

The error message is: ParseError: Unrecognised input

On this line: `#placement-5-1.sidenav(@sidenav-colour)`

Is there something obvious that I've missed? I'm new to less and am learning it for my new job. Thanks for any help here.

```css
#placement-5-1.sidenav(@sidenav-colour) {
 .content-wrapper-inner {
  ol.output-level-1 {
   box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
   > li {
    > a {
     background: @sidenav-colour;
     color: @bright-white;
     padding: 15px 10px;
     position: relative;
     padding-right: 40px;
     &:after {
      position: absolute;
      right: 10px;
      content: "\f063";
      font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
      font-size: 2em;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
 @media @mobile {
  margin: 0px 9% !important;
 }
}

@some-red: #e74c3c;
@some-blue: #3498db;

.sidenav.red { #placement-5-1.sidenav.red(@some-red) }
.sidenav.blue { #placement-5-1.sidenav.red(@some-blue) }
```

Comment: Not 100% sure but `#placement-5-1.sidenav(@sidenav-colour)` is dot allowed? Works for me when i remove the dot `.sidenav` that dot

Comment: i cant see why not

Comment: It's the name of the mixin, can't have a dot in it, it probably thinks it is a css class but then it's a mixin declaration so it can't parse it

Comment: *i cant see why not* - Basically a parametric mixin name must be a *single* identifier (obviously "one entity -> one name") You can get `.a.b.c.d....` things via nesting, e.g. like in [namespaces](http://lesscss.org/#namespaces-and-accessors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you declaring your mixin? Based on the code you posted here it looks like the variable @sidenav-colour was never declared so it would be an "unrecognized input". Try using this article to check that you're using the mixin correctly https://www.sitepoint.com/a-comprehensive-introduction-to-less-mixins/

Comment: I also suspect it's to do with sidenav-colour - but is my code not already declaring the sidenav-colour in the very first line? (I'm not familiar with LESS, but it seems identical to the examples I read like here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zXzGja and the link you provided) - and how do you declare the variables? thanks for the help

Comment: `@sidenav-colour` is a parameter that's passed into the mixin. Since it has no default value, it is a required variable for the mixin, has nothing to do with declaration